# how to use analysis.sentiment.polarity in indonesian to judge sentiment

Tags: python, tokenize, sentiment-analysis

i used sentiment analysis using python from twitter to judge whether its negative, positive, or neutral, with this code:

```
  hasilAnalisis = []
    
    for tweets in hasilUser:
        tweets_properties = {}
        tweets_properties['tanggal_tweet'] = tweets.created_at
        tweets_properties['pengguna'] = tweets.user.screen_name
        tweets_properties['isi_tweet'] = tweets.text
        tweets_full_cleansing = ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ",tweets.text).split())
        
        analysis = TextBlob(tweets_full_cleansing)
             
        try:
            analysis = analysis.translate(to='en')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0.0:
            tweets_properties["sentimen"] = "positif"
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0.0:
            tweets_properties["sentimen"] = "Netral"
        else:
            tweets_properties["sentimen"] = "Negatif"
            
            
        if tweets.retweet_count > 0:
            if tweets_properties not in hasilAnalisis:
                hasilAnalisis.append(tweets_properties)
        else:
        hasilAnalisis.append(tweets_properties)
```

the problem is, since the tweets that i want to find out is in indonesian, so i have to translate it first into english using this code

```
try:
            analysis = analysis.translate(to='en')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

after that the code can be judge or valued based on sentiment because there's already converted to english and `analysis.sentiment.polarity` can be done.

is there any way to do this without translate it into english first?

based on this https://ksnugroho.medium.com/dasar-text-preprocessing-dengan-python-a4fa52608ffe
i can use `sastrawi` for tokenization, but no idea how to use sentiment polarity in indonesian language.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated your question and I find a method for this. You can use:

1. [Sentiment Lexicon](https://github.com/fajri91/InSet) for Indonesian in [This Github link](https://github.com/rifkyahmadsaputra/Sentiment-Analysis-Online-Lectures-in-Indonesia)

Sentiment lexicon is usually has for every language.